# How to smooth scrolling using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, scroll

I am using scrollTop to scroll through content div using this

```
    var container = $('#content');
    container.scrollTop(
        $('#topic-' + id).offset().top - container.offset().top
    );

    container.scrollTop(
        container.scrollTop() + $('#topic-' + id).offset().top - container.offset().top
    );
```

It works. But the scrolling is hard on the eyes. Is there any way to ease the transistion.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) ...

You need to use the scrolltop as a method in the animation. i.e. :

```
.animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, 'ease')
```

Comment: yeah it's the best and fastest option. and there are also plugins for scrolling if you need something more, for example http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo